# Cannot apply my custom styles to HTML tags in ckeditor

Tags: wysiwyg, input-formats

I'm using Drupal 8 and am trying to make ckeditor truly wysiwyg.

To that end I've successfully gotten ckeditor to use a custom stylesheet by adding a ckeditor_sylesheets key to my theme's info.yml and my stylesheet's path as the value.

If within my custom stylesheet I create styles and assign them to a class, those styles are reflected within the form if I reference the class.

However, if within my stylesheet I define a style for an HTML element (e.g. h1, p, etc.) ckeditor ignores those styles.

This is the case regardless of how I set or unset "Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML" and "Correct faulty and chopped off HTML" at /admin/config/content/formats.

As I mentioned, clearly ckeditor is accessing my stylesheet as styles assigned to classes work.  Also, I can see the stylesheet in Chrome's inspector.  If I inspect a HTML tag for which I've defined a style it shows me that user agent stylesheet is being used.

I don't think it matters but just in case; I'm using Seven for my administrative theme and my default theme is a sub-theme of bootstrap.

If someone could give me a clue I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved this problem by clearing cache.  Not Drupal's cache (I'd tried that about a zillion times) Chrome's cache.  Duh.

Comment: Just for the future: In case of browser caching doubts, `Ctrl+F5` will do to reload ALL resources of the current page...

Comment: Thank you @Mario Steinitz for going the extra mile and providing a very useful tip re: clearing browser cache.